# How to convert image from folder into tensors using torch?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library, tensor

I'm trying to convert images in a folder to tensors, save it and load them later, as shown below

```py
transform = transforms.Compose([
  transforms.ToTensor()])
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
  r'imagedata', transform=transform) 
torch.save(dataset, 'train_data.pt')
```

But I get a value error when trying to load the trained file as below:

```
train_codes = torch.Tensor(torch.load(os.path.join(self.data_dir, "train_data.pt")))
```

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars

Any help or suggestion to fix this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You met this problem because `train_data.pt` was not saved as a Tensor, since that variable was read the data by `ImageFolder` which was inherited from [DatasetFolder](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder.html#torchvision.datasets.DatasetFolder), it should be loaded and used as a Torch Dataset. The example below use DataLoader as [documents](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html):

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms, datasets

# Saving part
transform = transforms.Compose([
                                transforms.ToTensor()
                               ])
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(r'imagedata', transform=transform) 
torch.save(dataset,'train_data.pt')

# Loading part
data = torch.load(torch.load(os.path.join(self.data_dir, "train_data.pt")))
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size = 32)
for image, label in loader:
   # Processing....
```

Comment: thanks for the answer this didn't fix my problem how can I save the file as tensor after reading from folder , I'm trying to run this library https://github.com/BGU-CS-VIL/DeepDPM inorder to run i've to pass directory containing tensor file as argument like python DeepDPM.py --dataset <dataset_name> --dir <embeddings path> , how can I modify above code to run this library